# Need to find if a one of two records are null

Tags: php

I am trying to check to confirm that both memberid and recipeid is not null. That way if both have value it will allow the member to ad the ripe to there list if both have a value it will tell them the recipe they are adding is already in there list. Working on this for a while need help and trying to transition from asp classic to php winky smile.

```
$check_fav = mysql_query("SELECT memberid, recipeid FROM favorites WHERE (memberid = '".$memberid."' AND recipeid = '".$id."')"); 

If ($check_fav == TRUE){.......
```

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Love the "winky smile".

Comment: am trying to check to confirm that both memberid and recipeid is not null. That way if both have different value (memberid is not null and recipeid IS NULL)it will allow the member to ad the recipe to there list; if both have a value it will tell them the recipe they are adding is already in there list. Working on this for a while need help and trying to transition from asp classic to php smile.

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_query()` never returns `true`. It returns a result object or `false` if an error occurred.

So this is the test you intended to do:

```
if ($check_fav !== false && mysql_fetch_row($check_fav) !== false) { ...
```

But before you do this, please move to *mysqli* functions (or object notation) instead of *mysql_*, as the latter are deprecated for ages now and no longer supported in PHP7. Also you are vulnerable to SQL injection. Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead.

Comment: My lord trincot you are a life saver thanks!!!